# Sast job not working if workflow rules declared in gitlab-ci.yaml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm creating a pipeline for my python project. Initially, I configured the SAST template in my pipeline. So now I want to add a custom job in my pipeline and I used workflow rules to declare variables. In this stage SAST job not getting triggered. Here is my `gitlab-ci.yaml` file.

**Before custom job implementation**

```
stages:
- test
sast:
  stage: test
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
```

**After custom job implementation**

```
stages:
- test
- customjob
sast:
  stage: test
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
- template: Path/to/Custom-job.yml

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"
      variables:
        CUSTOM_VAR: "Some_value"
    .
    .
    .
    ====conditions to different value to CUSTOM_VAR===
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the application security jobs are configured to run for branch pipelines only. To use them on merge request pipelines, you have to refer the latest SAST templates like so:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Jobs/SAST.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Source: [GitLab Application Security](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/#use-security-scanning-tools-with-merge-request-pipelines).